# How can I handle a Stripe webhook for paymentintent on a subscription when I have one-off charges too?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripes PHP SDK in an app that has a subscription and one-off charges.

I am tracking the following events via a webhook:

```
// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    // Fired for every payment, including subscriptions and one-offs
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $payment = $event->data->object;
        $this->handleOneOffPaymentSuccess($payment);
        break;
    // When a one-off payment fails
    case 'charge.failed':
        $payment = $event->data->object;
        $this->handleOneOffPaymentFailed($payment);
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
        $payment = $event->data->object;
        $this->handleOneOffPaymentFailed($payment, 'The payment was not authorized (#Virtuoso-3)');
        break;
    // Subscription handling
    case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
        $payment = $event->data->object;
        $this->handleSubscriptionPaymentSuccess($payment);
        break;
    // Subscription failure
    case 'invoice.payment_failed':
        $payment = $event->data->object; 
        $this->handleSubscriptionPaymentFailed($payment);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}
```

When a one-off payment is made I get a `payment_intent.succeeded`.  This has my metafield data in, so I can mark the item as purchased.  All good.

When I make a subscription I get a `invoice.payment_succeeded` event.  This has my metafield data in, so I can mark the subscription as paid.  Also all good.

However, along with the subscription I'm getting a `payment_intent.succeeded` event.  I presume this is because there's a charge taken.  I'm alright with that, but it doesn't contain any of the metafield data from when I created the subscription, so I have no way of tracking what it's for.  At the moment it's just failing, and that doesn't seem right.

Here's how I create the subscription:

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
    'customer' => $payment_method->stripe_customer_id, 
    'items' => [
        [
            'plan' => App::environment('production') ? $user->userType->stripe_plan : $user->userType->stripe_plan_test,
        ],
    ],
    'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    'metadata' => [
        'internal_subscription_id' => $internalSubscription->id,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
    ]
]);
```

Ideally I'd want that `user_id` to be part of the charge, then I can just log it against the user and show it to them along with their one-off charges.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 4):

You've got a couple of choices here:

1. Check the `invoice` [attribute on the payment intent object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-invoice). This will be set to an invoice ID when related to a subscription payment, and null for your one-time payments. Note: if you also use one-off invoices you'll need to handle that distinction too (retrieve the invoice and check the `subscription` attribute).
2. Set some `metadata` on your one-time payment intents. For example, set `'metadata' => [ 'onetime' => 'true']` and inspect this in your event handler.

Comment: metadata do not help because they are not passed down to every hook (at least on subscription cases)